# How to merge a folder with another folder (with everything in it)

Tags: batch-file

I would like to know how to copy a folder to another folder in a batch file.
I would like stuff with the same name to be overwritten.
Thanks.

Comment: Try to be more specific - are you trying to do this manually or by programming. If by programming, which programming language should be used, what have you tried so far..

Comment: If manually, download BeyondCompare and use it.  The trial is very nice, and it's worth the money it costs when you buy it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, the easiest way is with xcopy (provided you actually mean .bat files on Windows):

```
xcopy <SOURCE> <DEST> /e /d /y /h /r /c
```

To explain those flags:

```
/e: Include directories and sub directories even if empty
/d: Only copy files which have changed on SOURCE more recently than DEST
/y: Suppress prompts
/h: Also copy hidden and system files
/r: Override read-only files (e.g. ignore Read Only flag)
/c: Continue even if there are errors
```

Source: My standard backup script, been running every day for 6 years.

Answer (score 2):

or take a look at ROBOCOPY [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy)